# Scoping an admin link to only show for certain node bundles

Tags: 8, nodes, routes

I have 2 node content types / bundles, A and B. each A has a relationship with multiple Bs. When on the edit page, node/%/edit, for A, I want to show a link to the list of related B so that an editor can easily see a prefiltered list of B for A.

I have created a route:

in `my_module.routing.yml`

```
my_module.related_B:
  path: '/node/{node}/related_b'
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```

and have configured a view page at the same url `node/%/related_b` that contextually filters porperly. no issues there.

The link is added to the menu via the `my_module.links.task.yml`

```
my_module.related_B:
  route_name: my_module.related_B
  title: 'Related B'
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  weight: 100
```

Everything shows up and looks/works the way I want it to.

[image: related B example]

The problem is that I cannot seem to figure out how to limit that link/view to only show and work when on the edit page for an instance of content A. It shows on EVERY node edit page.

I've tried the following and did not seem to get anywhere:

- trying to hook into `hook_local_tasks_alter` in `my_module.module`
- custom `RouteSubscriber` Plugin

In D7 I was abel to accomplish this with a hook and access callback:

```
function my_module_menu()
{
    $items = array();

    // Single sync functionality
    $items['node/%node/related_B'] = array(
        'title' => 'Related B',
        'page callback' => '_B_page_callback',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => '_B_access_callback',
        'access arguments' => array(1),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function _A_access_callback($node)
{
    if($node->type == 'A' && user_access('administer nodes'))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I think it is possible to create such a link with Views (without custom code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. I mentioned that I had tried `hook_local_tasks_alter` when I should have been using [`hook_menu_local_tasks_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/8.7.x)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 * @param $local_tasks
 * @param $route_name
 * @param RefinableCacheableDependencyInterface $cacheability
 */
function mymodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$local_tasks, $route_name, RefinableCacheableDependencyInterface &$cacheability)
{
  if ($route_name == 'entity.node.edit_form') {
    $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
    $node = $route_match->getParameter('node');

    if ('A' != $node->bundle()) {
      unset($local_tasks['tabs'][0]['my_module.related_B']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to add a cache context: `$cacheability->addCacheContexts(['route']);`, otherwise this won't work in production when caching is enabled. BTW if you want to solve this the same way as now in D7 add a custom access check to the route, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes/custom-route-access-checking